# Multilevel Listbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'd like to make a multilevel (4-5 levels) Checked List Box for a WP7 page, so it looks like the dynamic tree shown in the picture:

[image: Example of multilevel-list]

I found a way to do a two-level list in [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-a-WP7-Checked-ListBox-in-different-ways), but how can I extend this so it can have 4-5 levels?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend against it. The UI approach here isn't suitable for a mobile platform. Could you clarify what you need this for?

Comment: I need to replicate the structure shown in the picture, which can be found in a regular web page, for a WP7 application.

Comment: And why do you need to do that? It's not suitable for a mobile platform in it's current state. It's more suitable for a mouse.

Comment: I need to do that because we're doing this application for a client and one of the features he demanded was that he could do a search using a similar structure to the one shown in the picture. As we were totally naive in mobile development, we said yes :P

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the LoopingListSelector from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) for this. Windows Phone Geek have [written a guide that illustrates how it could suit your purpose](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part2Implementing-a-generic-LoopingSelectorDataSource).

Though you probably wouldn't have screen space for more than 4 levels.